# cv-pls Helper Chrome Extension

Tags: script

### Screenshots

#### Formatted cv request

[image: cv-pls Helper in chat]

#### Settings

[image: settings]

### About

cv-pls Helper makes the process of closing questions easier on Stack Overflow.
There are a lot of 'bad' questions being asked and to [help reduce the noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/120275/is-asking-others-for-a-close-vote-appropriate) these
questions should be closed as fast as possible.

This extension in no way automagically closes questions on a close vote request,
but rather makes the review process better.

The extension parses [cv-pls] and [delv] requests in the chat of Stack Overflow.
An example of a request is: `[tag:cv-pls] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991825/arabic-in-extjs-grid`.
When the extension sees a request it will parse it into a nice onebox.
Optionally it will also notify the user by sound (Stack Overflow chat @mention beep)
or by avatar notification (like mention / flag popup).

Also check out [this post](https://gist.github.com/1689430) for more information about the "cv-ring" process
and why it is needed.

#### License

Released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html).

#### Download

Download the [latest version](https://cv-pls.pieterhordijk.com/) (0.20.1).

#### Platform

The extension is tested on Google Chrome 11+ on Linux and Windows. If you have
any issues using other versions of OS, Chrome or a combination let me know
and I might fix it.

### Contact

The extension is created by [PeeHaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/repwhoringpeehaa) (Pieter Hordijk) and contains
contributions from [Hakre](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre). Also special thanks to [rdlowrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895378/rdlowrey) for testing
the extension.
You can find us on GitHub: [Hakre](https://github.com/hakre), [rdlowrey](https://github.com/rdlowrey) and [PeeHaa](https://github.com/PeeHaa) or in the
[PHP chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

### Code

The extension is built using Javascript and uses the jQuery library (yeah I know
jQuery sucks ;) ).
The source can be download form the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cv-pls/). You can fork the repo if
you want to contribute or you can submit [an issue](https://github.com/cv-pls/cv-pls/issues) if you find one or when you
want to make a feature request.

Comment: update the current version link =o)